# Gulp compile CSS multiple src

Tags: gulp, less

I am using Gulp to compile my bootstrap.less file into a bootstrap.css file. All the bootstrap LESS files are in a "less" folder and all of the CSS files are in a CSS folder. All of the bootstrap less files are @import'd into bootstrap.less and then that file is compiled to bootstrap.css. However I have one custom.less file that is in the bootstrap LESS folder. I would like to compile into a custom.css file in the CSS folder. I cannot get Gulp to do this. Here is my code.

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var less       = require('gulp-less');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('less', function() {
return gulp.src(['./less/bootstrap.less', './less/custom.less'])
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./css"))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('serve', function(){

        browserSync.init({
            server: {
                baseDir: './'
            }
        });

gulp.watch('./less/*.less', ['less']);
gulp.watch(['./**/*.html', './js/custom.js']).on('change',
browserSync.reload);

});

gulp.task( 'default', ['less', 'serve']);
```

Comment: what if you do like this: gulp.task('less', function() {
return gulp.src(['./less/*.less''])
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./css/custom.css"))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

Comment: Wouldn't that pipe all of my less files into custom.css? I'm looking to have compile all the boostrap.less files into bootstrap.css and separately compile custom.less into custom.css.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is compile all .less or .scss files into css folder. You will end up with a few empty files (a good example would be .less files that contain variables) but on the other hand you can create a gulp task to clear those files out. I use the following code to compile:

```
return gulp.src("Styles/scss/*.scss")
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(sass())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest("Styles/css"))
  .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
```

I'm also generating sourcemaps here but you can remove that. If you would like to discover more checkout [this post here](http://www.ossipov.eu/how-to-use-browsersync-gulp-and-sass-to-fast-track-your-front-end-development/)

Hope this helps ;)